# Android : Java.NullPointerException error on my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, nullpointerexception

i'm new here but I read every day questions on this forum.
I'm building a music player based on a side drawer on the left (using the library "simple side drawer), when I touch the up button (on the action bar) then the left drawer open.
On the left drawer there is a listview (simple) with all your's songs. When I tap on a item then that should start playing...but the app crash.
This is the error

```
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at com.xand.holomusicplayer.Maincu$1.onItemClick(Maincu.java:58)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:297)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1123)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2931)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.widget.AbsListView$2.run(AbsListView.java:3616)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why, this is the code:

```
private String[] mAudioPath;
 private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
 private String[] mMusicList;
 private SimpleSideDrawer mSlidingMenu;
 ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mSlidingMenu = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
    mSlidingMenu.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    list = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView1);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMusicList = getAudioList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
        try {
            playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
       });
    }
private String[] getAudioList() {
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();

    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }   

    mCursor.close();

    return songs;
}

private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
IllegalStateException, IOException {

Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

mMediaPlayer.reset();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);       
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        mSlidingMenu.toggleLeftDrawer();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

why the app crash when I try to play something ? Please Help me :( :)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 14:33:58.760: E/AndroidRuntime(12420):    at com.xand.holomusicplayer.Maincu$1.onItemClick(Maincu.java:58)`  What is line 58?  Looks like gahfy is right.  Where do you initialise and set mAudioPath?

Comment: } catch (IOException e) {

Comment: Nope.  That line cannot cause this exception.  Either the code you have posted is not exactly the same as when you run it and get the exception, you have counted the lines incorrectly or you have not learned that your IDE editor shows line numbers in the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All other things aside, your NullPointerException from onItemClick() method happens probably when you do:

```
playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
```

The reason for this is that mAudioPath is not initialised and null. Why?

You have declared it as a field in your class Maincu as:

```
private String[] mAudioPath;
```

You think you are initialising it by calling getAudioList(), but inside this method, you are declaring:

```
String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
```

which SHADOWS your global variable mAudioPath, so your local mAudioPath is being initialised, instead of global, which is then used to play the song. To fix, in your getAudioList(), change:

```
String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
```

to:

```
mAudioPath = new String[count];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `mAudioPath` member is null. Be sure to set it before calling `onItemClick()`.